# Recover original file names from Volume Shadow Copy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, windows-vista, vss

In the Volume Shadow Copy folders there are some cryptically names files like:

`\System Volume Information\{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}`

Is there any way to decipher what the file name was before it was put in the `System Volume Information` folder?

Comment: VSC has always given me readable names for a given timestamped folder.  Where are you finding this?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't have a file name before it "got put in `System Volume Information`."  (Assuming you're talking about the files as in the below screenshot.)

[image]

[They're system files used by the Volume Shadow Service for holding restore point data](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/16/identifying-how-much-disk-space-is-used-for-restore-points-in-windows-vista.aspx).  You can use `vssadmin list shadows` and `vssadmin list shadowstorage` to get more information on your assorted shadow copies, but those files are where the Volume Shadow Service crams the data it needs to do a restore, so it's not any one existing file, *per se*, it's a bunch of files and/or system state information crammed into one big file object.

In Vista/7/2008, at least - on older versions of Windows you could browse the `System Volume Information` folder to see exactly what files it had backed up.  Not so much on the newer Windows OSes.